# Tokenize string in python using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, tokenize

I've input data in the following format, not decided by me

```
key1: value1 key2: value2 key3: value3 key4 { key11: val11 key22: value22 } key5: value5 ............
```

The input string will have key values separated by colon or a brace bracket.

I want to tokenize it and I have the following idea:
First to have a regular expression parsing data till I find a `:` or `{` with priority to `{` over `:`

Then split and read till the white space pattern that I said is reached and recursively traverse the whole string

I want to know if I can write a regex like (some_string)(special character pattern)
(special character pattern can be `:` or `{` with precedence to `{`)(rest of the string)

If it is a `:` then for rest of the string, get the string part from ' value1 ' and capture it. Work on the remaining string

If it is a `{` then traverse till you find `}` and internally work with `:` logic defined above.

For eg

```
a: 1 b: 2 c { d: 3 e: 4 } f: 5
```

This should give

```
a:1
b:2
c { d: 3 e: 4 }
f: 5
```

Comment: Is regex a requirement, or would you be OK with a function?

Comment: @SethMMorton FUnction is also ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
[^ ]+(?:: [^ ]+| \{[^}]+\})
```

example:

```
import re
test = "a: 1 b: 2 c { d: 3 e: 4 } f: 5"
pattern = re.compile(r"[^ ]+(?:: [^ ]+| \{[^}]+\})")
for match in pattern.findall(test):
    print match
```

Comment: This only gave the first key and not the remaining keys,

Comment: @gizgok: test the example, you must use findall

Comment: I downvoted initially because there was no explanation, just the pattern. With the addition of the example, I have reversed my downvote, and in fact upvoted the answer.